# CredentialCache with IIS vs personal development server

Tags: c#, ssis, webserver, credentials, iis-5

I have a webservice that I am testing.  When I use the personal asp.net webserver, the one with the random port everything works fine.  It uses my credentials when I pass DefaultCredentials to an ssrs server to run a report.

When I tried to move it to my local IIS server, the DefualtCredentials UserName is blank and the ID that gets pass to the SSRS server is ASPNET.

I turned off Annon access and only Integrated Windows Authentication is on.

My local IIS is 5.1, so it doesn't have application pools as a separate object.

In the web.config authentication is set

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I do have the

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

now, but my problem is trickier then originally stated.

The outer webservice calls SSRS webservice and now it works fine in the browser.
But when I call the outer webservice from within SSIS, it does not work, when I step through the code the call to the outer webservice occurs but when I make the call to SSRS i get a 401 Authentication error.

I have valid credentials in the HTTP Manager.  I have the package protection level at EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey.

Again if I call the outer webservice from a personal ASP.net webserver, even the SSIS works fine.  I just have to download the wsdl every time because the port changes and then I have to re-setup the webservice task.  I am concern when I go to production.

(I have yet to run a test from code to see how the webservice acts)

**UPDATE 2**

Again the webservice works in IE, but not in SSIS nor Firefox even when I supply my credentials when I hit the webservice

I know I am getting authenticated properly because

```
User.Identity.Name
```

returns my login name in the webservice, but when I assign defaultCredentials to the reporting service service it still gives me 401 error.  I even tried to impersonate the log in that I was logged in as

```
Dim win As System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity = CType(User.Identity, System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity)
Dim context As System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext = win.Impersonate()

    reportService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```

Comment: Does your web.config contain the "impersonation"? You might want to try that will impersonation turned on, otherwise the credentials should be the 'IIS account' like 'ASPNET' (if i still remember IIS 5 correctly).

Comment: Yes, I did get that far, please see updated info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I received from Microsoft.

It was my pleasure to discuss your issue over the phone littler earlier. As I was saying that HTTP connection manager does not support Windows Authentication, please have a look at the article at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140114.aspx

```
Important

The HTTP connection manager supports only anonymous authentication and basic 
authentication. It does not support Windows Authentication.
```

So, at this point using Script Task to call the Web Services would be an option, however you mentioned that there will be a challenge of moving the package to QA to UAT etc. I agree with you that managing the URL in the proxy class is a challenge.

Please let me know if you have further questions.

---

Now even this is not true because I showed the gentleman from Microsoft that our web service did require Windows Authentication but what is not working is known as the “double-hop”.  That is the credentials do not get passed to the SSRS server.